# How to set custom continuation line indentation in Vim for Java source files

Tags: java, vim

I want to customize the indentation of continuation lines for Java in Vim. The default settings (using `filetype plugin indent on`) indent continuation lines by 1 `shiftwidth`, but I would like it to be twice that much.

For example, if `shiftwidth=2`, I want this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final Logger logger = 
      Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
}
```

instead of this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final Logger logger = 
    Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
}
```

So far I have tried to do this by adding `setlocal cinoptions+=+2s` to my `.vimrc/after/ftplugin/java.vim` file, but to no avail. Executing `:scriptnames` in Vim revealed that `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/java.vim` is being loaded **after** my script and overrides any previous settings on `cinoptions`, effectively thwarting my efforts and dashing my dreams of custom continuation line indentation.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong file. Use `.vim/after/indent/java.vim` - you want it to load after indent, not after ftplugin.